# Swift: Copying oldArray[][] to newArray[][] causes error (Type 'Any' has no subscript member)

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, collections, plist

Using Swift for my collectionView app. I'm reading a plist file to display the info in the arrays.

This is the code to read the plist which creates an array called sections[section #][item #] which lets me access items inside the arrays of the root.

```
var Items = [Any]()

let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource:"items", withExtension: "plist")!
    do {
        let data = try Data(contentsOf:url)
        let sections = try PropertyListSerialization.propertyList(from: data, format: nil) as! [[Any]]

        for (index, section) in sections.enumerated() {
            //print("section ", index)
            for item in section {
                //print(item)
            }
        }
        print("specific item: - \(sections[1][0])") // (Section[] Item[])
        print("section count: - \(sections.count)")

        Items = sections

    } catch {
        print("This error must never occur", error)
    }

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    switch checkGroupChoice {
    case 0:
        print("From: Items")

        print("specific item 2: - \(Items[0][1])")

        return Items.count
```

I created `var Items = [Any]()` to transfer everything from `sections[][]` to the array Items so I can use it as a global array for my collectionsView but I get an error.

> Type 'Any' has no subscript members

on the line `print("specific item 2: - \(Items[0][1])")`

How do I successfully transfer `sections[][]` to `Items`? I'm sure I'm not creating the array correctly. Thank you

Comment: Items is a ONE dimensional array.. you are trying to index it as a 2D array.. Change it to `var Items = [[Any]]()`

Comment: perfect so simple, thanks! you can add it as an answer if you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Items is a ONE dimensional array.. you are trying to index it as a 2D array.. Change it to:

`var Items = [[Any]]()`

Now you can assign to it and append to it and index it as a 2D array. Each dimension requires a matching set of square brackets..

Example:

```
1D array:  [Any]()
2D array:  [[Any]]()
3D array:  [[[Any]]]()
```